# HTML Validation with Certain Rules

Tags: html, regex, validation

How can I write a validation in HTML with below rules?

- User ID total length should be **7 characters** including alphabets and numbers
- User ID **must be start with alphabets** [**A-Z** / **a-z**] and it should be **2** characters
- Remaining 5 characters should be numbers **[0-9]**

Examples:

**ab12345**, **xy56879**, **pm30075**

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="userid">User ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" value="" required  pattern="[A-Za-z]{2}+[0-9]{5}" title="User ID" aria-required="true" placeholder="Eg: ab12345">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>    
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" required  title="Email" aria-required="true" placeholder="hello.world@happyworld.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below pattern will do

```
pattern="(?=.*[A-Za-z]{2})(?=.*[0-9]{5}).{7,7}"
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dzwwfg4m/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `+` from your pattern:

```css
input:invalid { outline: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}" required="true" placeholder="Eg: ab12345">
```